# Interview: Find Ranges of All Consecutive Numbers

Tags: algorithm

Given a sorted array with some sequenced numbers and some non-sequenced numbers. Write an algorithm that takes this array as an input and returns a list of {start, end} of all consecutive numbers. Consecutive numbers have difference of 1 only.

E.g. of array:

`[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 27]`

```
public class Range
{
    private int begin;
    private int end;
    public int begin { get; set; }
    public int end { get; set; }
}
```

The O(n) solution here seems obvious, but is there a way to do it in less time?

Comment: In worst case, you have to look at each number at least once. So I don't think you can do better than `O(n)` in worst case.

Comment: Any language preference?

Comment: @Anirudh Preference is Java, C++, or C.

Comment: Can you clarify what output you expect?

For your sample input, is your result 4,9; or is it 15,18; or is it 22,24; or will any of those answers be OK? ...since your input has 3 consecutive subsequences.

Comment: @WillBriggs It will be a list containing those three Range objects

Comment: Does the input list have duplicates?

Comment: Thanks, John.  Based on your clarification, RADAR's answer below (in particular, his last paragraph) is dead on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is to move ahead by say 3 numbers at a time and see the difference between them

if the difference is equal to 3 then they are consecutive , then move ahead by another 3 till you find that difference is not 3, then you move back by one step and do the difference if it is 2 then end the range and start your next  range from the previous number where we had the difference.

In the worst case, where there is no consecutive numbers at all, we will iterate n/3 times for large N, this matters.

EDIT:

The worst case with this approach is when there are two consecutive pair of numbers, where we need to touch all numbers , so it is going to be O(n) in that particular case.